# Not able to see graphical layout of XML :Missing Themes

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-xml, android-theme

I am facing problem in eclipse that I have a layout and I want to see its graphical view but in there it is showing  blank space with message

```
!SESSION 2014-01-17 14:27:41.124 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

This is a continuation of log file /root/AndroidHome/AndroidWorkspace/.metadata/.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2014-01-17 17:02:55.764

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.764
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.765
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.765
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.765
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.766
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.766
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.767
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.767
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.767
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.768
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.768
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.768
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.769
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.770
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.770
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.770
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.771
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.771
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.771
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.772
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.772
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.772
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.772
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.773
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.774
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.774
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.774
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.775
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.775
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.775
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.775
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.776
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.777
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.777
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.777
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.777
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.778
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.778
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.778
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.779
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.779
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.779
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.779
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.780
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.780
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.780
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.781
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.782
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.782
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.782
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.782
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.783
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.783
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.783
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.784
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.784
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.784
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.785
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.786
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.786
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.786
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.786
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.787
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.787
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.787
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.788
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.788
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.788
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.789
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.789
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.790
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.790
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'spinnerStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.790
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.791
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.791
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.791
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.792
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.793
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.793
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.793
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.794
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.794
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.794
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.794
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 2 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.798
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Couldn't find theme resource attr/listPreferredItemHeight for the current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 2 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.798
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: "?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" in attribute "minHeight" is not a valid format.

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.798
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.799
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 2 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.799
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Couldn't find theme resource attr/textAppearanceListItem for the current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 2 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.800
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: Couldn't find theme resource attr/textAppearanceListItem for the current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-01-17 17:02:55.800
!MESSAGE updatebalance_layout.xml: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
!STACK 0
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:468)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:48)
```

I am not getting what should I to see this XML in graphical view .Please help

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/balance_txt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Balance"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="14.0dip" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/balace_to_update"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="34.0dip"
                android:background="@drawable/formedbackground"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textColor="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amt_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
                android:text="Amount"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="14.0dip" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/amount_got"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="34.0dip"
                android:background="@drawable/formedbackground"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textColor="@color/blue" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/payment_type_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
                android:text="Payment Type"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="14.0dip" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/paymenttypespin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="34.0dip"
                android:padding="0.0dip"
                android:textColor="@color/blue" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/action_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Reduce"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="14.0dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/balance_cur_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Currency"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="14.0dip" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="34.0dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/action_button"
                    android:layout_width="57.0dip"
                    android:layout_height="34.0dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/reduce" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/balance_currency"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="19.0dip"
                    android:text="INR"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="14.0dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amt_currency_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
                android:text="Currency"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="14.0dip" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/amount_currency"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="34.0dip"
                android:padding="0.0dip"
                android:textColor="@color/blue" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/partial_entries"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10.0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5.0"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ifpartial_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="if partial"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="14.0dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/partialamt_txt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Partial Amount"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="14.0dip" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/partial_amout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="34.0dip"
                android:background="@drawable/formedbackground"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:inputType="phone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
            android:layout_weight="5.0"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/partial_currency_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Currency"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="14.0dip" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/partial_amount_currency"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="34.0dip"
                android:padding="0.0dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mode_entries"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mode_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Payment Mode "
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="14.0dip" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/payment_mode"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="34.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="5.0"
                android:entries="@array/mode_arrays"
                android:padding="0.0dip" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/other_mode_ed"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="34.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="5.0"
                android:background="@drawable/formedbackground"
                android:hint="Other Mode"
                android:textColor="@color/blue" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="34.0dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/formedbackground"
        android:hint="Description"
        android:minLines="4"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update_balance_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45.0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="Save Changes"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18.0dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can paste here the message...

Comment: Check if you have used the correct theme in Graphic Layout view of your xml file.

Comment: @hypd09 I have not used any theme in xml

Comment: You need to specify a theme in your manifest file and use the same to allow eclipse render your views. If you have created your project using eclipse it must have created a default theme. Just find [this field(Imguraffe in my app)](http://i.imgur.com/klnfKiC.png) and click it for options and use the one in Manifest.

Comment: @hypd09 in manifiest  "@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" this has been set as theme and same is showing in option you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close Your .XML files and restart eclipse

Comment: Try changing the SDK value and then restart

Comment: @PsyGik what do you mean by SDK value? Please rephrase.

Comment: @eMAD, change the Target SDK using which you are building the project. On Android Studio it is called Compile SDK Version.

Answer (score 1):

got to your xml file and choose api level below 21
and change the theme Holo light

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for writing the new answer instead of leaving a comment.

> Close Your .XML files and restart eclipse

This PsyGik's solution has worked for my project on Android Studio. :)